# select two tables and print the columns side by side with matching key in hive

Tags: scripting, python, hadoop

I have the below tables:

**table_1**

```
name_1  id_1    value_1
avi        1    21
adi        2    X
```

**table_2**

```
name_2  id_2    value_2
avi        1    21
adi        2    22
```

**metadata_info**: can be read from a file or hard coded

```
table_1_col  table_2_col
name_1       name_2
id_1         id_2
value_1      value_2
```

I want the below result:

```
table_1_col  table_2_col  table_1.name_1  table_2.name_2  table_1.id_1  table_2.id_2  table_1.value_1  table_2.value_2  flag
name_1       name_2       avi             adi             1             1             21               21               0
name_1       name_2       avi             adi             2             2             X                21               1
```

I am trying to do the entire process in a shell script, and I want to run multiple Hive queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'table_1' AS table_1
    ,'table_2' AS table_2
    ,'id_1' AS table_1_pk
    ,'id_2' AS table_2_pk
    ,t1.id_1 table_1_pk_value
    ,t2.id_2 AS table_2_pk_value
    ,'name_1' AS table_1_col
    ,'name_2' AS table_2_col
    ,t1.name_1 AS table_1_value
    ,t2.name_2 AS table_2_value
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.name_1 = t2.name_2
            THEN '0'
        WHEN t1.name_1 <> t2.name_2
            THEN '1'
        END AS flag
FROM table_1 AS t1
FULL JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t1.id_1 = t2.id_2;
```